# Print variable from other file with raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, raw-input

So I'm just starting out on a project here. For starters, I have two files.

The first file is myDict.py. In there I store variables that I want to be able to fetch.
myDict.py:

```
numbers = [1, 5, 8, 61]
wallet = [20, 50, 100, 1000]
```

So there I have two lists in that file, now to the mainfile. I wanted to choose which list I wanted to print from raw_input, but I don't know how I would be able to do that. I haven't directly gotten anywhere since I do not know how to be able to do this.

I know I can do this to print a selected variable from myDict.py:

```
import myDict
print myDict.wallet
```

But I can't find a way to do it with raw_input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`getattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get arbitrary attributes named in a variable from the module:

```
import myDict

list_name = 'wallet'
print getattr(myDict, list_name)
```

Simply use `raw_input()` to ask the user for either `wallet` or `numbers` and you are set!

```
import myDict

list_name = raw_input('wallet or numbers? ')
print getattr(myDict, list_name)
```

You may want to use a `try:`/`except AttributeError:` to catch mistakes:

```
list_name = raw_input('wallet or numbers? ')
try:
    print getattr(myDict, list_name)
except AttributeError:
    print "Sorry, no such list"
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Wasn't aware of that function, but it sure was the one I needed! Now I can continue with the project :)